# React-Contextmenu - console.log() doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, contextmenu, console.log

I have a small problem in React.
I added the following extention to my project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contextmenu

Can you explain me why console.log inside the "MenuItem" is not working but outside it works?

```
<ContextMenu id="test">
   <MenuItem>
    {/* no console log :( */}
    <a onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();console.log('Inside MenuItem');}}>Click Me</a>
   </MenuItem>
    {/* console log works */}
    <a onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();console.log('Inside MenuItem');}}>Click Me</a>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to prevent the default behavior of the link:</strike>

```
<a onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();console.log('Inside MenuItem');}}>Click Me</a>
```

You also need to attach onClick as props inside MenuItem Component. Here's a sample of MenuItem that will attach the onClick as props:

```
const MenuItem = props => {
  // ...other holds all other props except desiredProps
  const { disiredProps, ...other } = props;
  // ...other holds onClick props
  return <div {...other}>{other.children}</div>
  //              ^^ onClick is passed as props
}
```

Since the MenuItem component is a part of the `react-contextmenu`, you cannot assign the event handler inside the children, because you cannot work directly on MenuItem component to denote your children event handler as props. What you need to do is to define the handler in MenuItem itself:

```
<MenuItem onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();console.log('Inside MenuItem');}}>
  <a>Click MenuItem</a><!-- though unnecessary link tag -->
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.

your result works also outside "<MenuItem>". But inside still no console.log :/

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Does the console.log work outside the contextmenu, could you test that first?

Comment: hey, i updated my first post (changed image to code).
yes console.log works fine outside my MenuItem

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and there is a bug in the context menu

That is why the developers from Context menu advise this:

```
function handleClick(e, data) {
```

console.log(data.foo);
}

function MyApp() {
  return (

```
  <ContextMenuTrigger id="some_unique_identifier">
    <div className="well">Right click to see the menu</div>
  </ContextMenuTrigger>

  <ContextMenu id="some_unique_identifier">
      <MenuItem data={{foo: 'bar'}} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      ContextMenu Item 1
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem data={{foo: 'bar'}} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      ContextMenu Item 2
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem data={{foo: 'bar'}} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      ContextMenu Item 3
    </MenuItem>
  </ContextMenu>

</div>
```

);
}

To do the console.log outside in a different methode,

Check out the git isue

https://github.com/vkbansal/react-contextmenu/issues/161

there was no solution provide and this is not a while ago
So I don't think you re code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<ContextMenu id="test">
   <MenuItem onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();console.log('Inside MenuItem');}}>
    Click Me
   </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```